# How to store files in zip / rar archive with Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, zip, archive, rar

I´m working on an app where I need to store pictures in an archive and send them as attachment in email.

How can I create a zip file / rar file and save the pictures in it?

I´ve been searching all day long and nothing works for me. Tried this for example:
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-programmatically-zip-and-unzip-file-in-android

Thanks!

Comment: "nothing works" doesn't tell us anything useful.  Instead, explain what specific errors you're having with the solution you're attempting.

Answer (score 0):

I use SharpLibZip.Portable library (http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) . You can get it in your Nuget Package Manager.

It works fine in Android and UWP (not proved for me in iOS).